# Family parent child relation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqQ7i.jpg)

I need the following hierarchy showing in the following image

I have write the following code with cte :
--=========================

```
;With Hierarchy (Name,Path)
AS
(
SELECT t.FamilyName, CAST(t.FamilyName AS varchar(max))
FROM tblFamily t
LEFT JOIN tblFamily t1
ON t1.FamilyID = t.ParentFamilyId
WHERE t1.FamilyID IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT t.FamilyName, CAST('All Categories'+'>'++h.FamilyName + '->' + t.FamilyName AS varchar(max))
FROM tblFamily h
INNER JOIN tblFamily t
ON t.FamilyID = h.ParentFamilyId
)



SELECT Name,Path
FROM Hierarchy
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

i have hardcoded the All categories which is the parent to all the child but i also need this natural how to do this?
Here is the table :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t30TO.png)

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Aside... as some people are fond of saying around here: `;` is a statement terminator, not a statement begininator. You should terminate all of your SQL Statements with the `;` character, not just put one in front of the ones that can generate errors such as `WITH`.

Comment: First off with a with a hierarchy you require an anchor. Which is the main table and the main table only on its NULL condition. The following answer helps with the structure and explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47660012/t-sql-hierarchy-query

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the tree in the wrong direction. It's much easier in this case to start at the top of the tree and work down.

```sql
WITH Hierarchy
AS
(
    SELECT t.FamilyID, t.FamilyName, FamilyPath = CAST(t.FamilyName AS varchar(max))
    FROM tblFamily t
    WHERE t.ParentFamilyId IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.FamilyID, t.FamilyName, h.FamilyPath + ' > ' + t.FamilyName
    FROM tblFamily t
    INNER JOIN Hierarchy h ON h.FamilyID = t.ParentFamilyId
)
SELECT
  FamilyID,
  FamilyName,
  FamilyPath
FROM Hierarchy;
```

Note that using `MAXRECURSION 0` is usually a bad idea, because most trees don't go anywhere near that far, and this could cause an infinite recursion if there is a loop in the hierarchy.

Comment: Hello, There is no FamilyID column when you are using Hierarchy table for join after Union All. Its generating an error

Comment: Just add it to the CTE, as shown

Comment: The assignment (first image) specifically says to use OUTER JOIN to self join using three references to the same table, and even specifies which table aliases to use. Recursive CTE is the way I'd go, but it's not answering the question the OP is meant to be answering.

Comment: I note that that appears in text as part of the image for the assignment. It really should have been in the question text in the post. OP themselves used a CTE. If you feel this needs a different answer you are welcome to provide it yourself

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment tells you to user outer joins to link three references to the same table, and even tells you what to alias the tables.  There's nothing about CTEs or recursion.

```
SELECT
  Family.*,
  COALESCE(TopFamily.FamilyName + ' > ', '')
  + COALESCE(ParentFamily.FamilyName + ' > ', '')
  + Family.FamilyName
    AS FamilyPath
FROM
  tblFamily   AS Famiky
LEFT JOIN
  tblFamily   AS ParentFamily
    ON ParentFamily.FamilyID = Family.ParentFamilyID
LEFT JOIN
  tblFamily   AS TopFamily
    ON TopFamily.FamilyID = ParentFamily.ParentFamilyID
```

The first reference gets all family entries, regardless of level in the hierarchy.

The left join gets the parent, if there is one, and NULLs if there isn't one. The second left join does the same again, essentially getting the Grandparent, if there is one.

***This means that it only works for a set depth, but that's what your assignment asked for.***

The `SELECT` clause wraps each level's `FamilyName` in a `COALESCE()`, so that the `>` is only added to the name if it isn't `NULL`, and replaces any `NULL` with an empty string (joining `NULL` to another string just gives `NULL`).